# How to SELECT unique rows from 3 JOINED tables

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to check if a persons name appears multiple times in a table aswell as pull additional information (position title, department name, employee number) to limit creating two stored procedures 1. to check if name appears multiple times and 2. to get the additional information after check has been completed.

my current query right now is as follows, which returns multiple rows as the ID I am using to join the tables appears multiple times in one table (an employee can belong to multiple departments, the EmpID occurs here multiple times thyus returning the multiple values).

```
SELECT c.FirstName+ ' ' + c.LastName as emp_full_name, e.EmployeeNumber,
       e.EmpID, dh.PositionTitle, d.Name as deptName, e.isActive

FROM Person.Contact c

INNER JOIN HumanResources.Employee e ON c.ContactID = e.ContactID
INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory dh ON e.EmpID = dh.EmpID
INNER JOIN HumanResources.Department d ON dh.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID

WHERE c.FirstName+ ' ' + c.LastName LIKE @empName
```

My general table structure is as follows:

### Person.Contact

ContactID

FirstName

LastName

### HumanResources.Employee

EmpID

EmployeeNumber

isActive

### HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory

DepartmentHistoryId

EmpID

DepartmentID

PositionTitle

### HumanResources.Department

DepartmentID

Name

Example Result Set:

```
John Doe 1234567  1 Database Architect Administration    A
John Doe 1234567  1 Database Tester    Administration    A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Distinct keyword

```
SELECT distinct c.FirstName+ ' ' + c.LastName as emp_full_name, e.EmployeeNumber,
       e.EmpID, STUFF((
      SELECT ',' + edh.PositionTitle
      FROM dbo.EmployeeDepartmentHistory edh
      WHERE edh.EmpID = e.EmpID
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ''), e.isActive

FROM Person.Contact c

INNER JOIN HumanResources.Employee e ON c.ContactID = e.ContactID
INNER JOIN HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory dh ON e.EmpID = dh.EmpID
INNER JOIN HumanResources.Department d ON dh.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID

WHERE c.FirstName+ ' ' + c.LastName LIKE @empName
Group By e.EmpID
```

Comment: I have attempted this but it will still return two rows if an employee belongs to multiple department positions. I want it to query the Person.Contact for unique occurrences of an employees full name. THEN also give me the additional information I am querying for

Comment: In that case you have to exclude deptName Column

Comment: Negative, if I do this then I loose the information I have to query for. writing a simple select statement to check for unique values of the person.contact on the employee name would suffice BUT I am trying to query additional information at the same time to limit database accesses

Comment: If there are multiple department for an employee and you need to show them in single row then you can use concatinate dept name

Comment: edit your answer to reflect this ? I'm not sure I understand completely I have altered my procedure and it still returns me the duplicate rows , just without deptName clearly...

Comment: You mean when you exclude d.Name it still gives multiple row for an employee?

Comment: Yes, I forgot the EmpID in HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory in my table structure above I have now added it and I am sure you'll understand why it is still returning duplicates.

Is there no way to join these two queries am I just approaching this incorrectly? Do I need to access the database twice for this set of information I'm after? I believe no..

Comment: Tell me the columns name whose values are different in duplicate rows.There must be a column whose values are different.

Comment: ok for example if I search for John Doe and he belongs to two positions the result would look like this

see question so I can properly format the result set, im new to forums

Comment: Checkout  my modified answer

Comment: Syntax Error near " ',' " , going to google GROUP_CONCAT()

EDIT GROUP_CONCAT is not supported in sql server 2005 looks like I need to do another query and then join the result sets?

Comment: LOL! thanks a lot Syeda! I manipulated the first alteration of GROUP_CONCAT you posted and I got it working :) thanks for putting the additional edit to reflect more closely to my table names :p

ACCEPTED as answer Also had to update the group by to include what was not in the select statement or an aggregate function

Comment: Now the true test is , if an employee only belongs to ONE dept :D but thanks now I can get back 'wired in' and get a lot done !

Comment: yeah ... if the employee only belongs to 1 department this fails miserably :D , I think all I need is a left join on the department history ?